# Do i need to call the class "File Stream" to encrypt the data in a file?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, filestream

I made a program that iterates through a directory, finds files with a specific extension, and then encrypts it. Although it's not encrypting the actual file, it's encrypting the file directory.
It is a console application that shows the encrypted message and the decrypted message as well.
here is the core part of the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string root = @"C:\Users\Owner\Documents";
    var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root) select file;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.EndsWith(".txt"))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create Aes that generates a new key and initialization vector (IV).    
                // Same key must be used in encryption and decryption    
                using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
                {
                    // Encrypt string    
                    byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(file, aes.Key, aes.IV);
                    // Print encrypted string    
                    Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted data: {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted)}");
                    // Decrypt the bytes to a string.    
                    string decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, aes.Key, aes.IV);
                    // Print decrypted string. It should be same as raw data    
                    Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted data: {decrypted}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

output:

Encrypted data: ?U↔C?♣#Y?f"?8?a?*????♦????&?,¶?

Decrypted data: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\script.txt

I go into the file and nothing is encrypted inside it

Comment: You aren't _writing_ the encrypted data anywhere.

Comment: @mjwills: Sure he is. To the console :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at these lines

```
byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(file, aes.Key, aes.IV);
```

This encrypts the *name* of your file, not the *contents* of the file. To encrypt the contents, you can replace this with

```
byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(File.ReadAllText(file), aes.Key, aes.IV);
```

Now let's examine

```
// Print encrypted string    
Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted data {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted)}");
```

This part is fine. It writes the encrypted content to the console (only). If you want to write it back to the original file (thus encrypting the file), you could instead or in addition do

```
File.WriteAllText(file, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted));
```

Similarly for decrypting, you need to read the contents of the encrypted file and write the decrypted contents back to the file.